# Bug? FlashPlayer 10 Projector not going into fullscreen depending on SWF/HTML Player settings

Tags: settings, flash, fullscreen, publish, projector

We now use Flash CS4 to publish our FlashPlayer (SWF) and Projector (EXE) but have been having problems with the Projector not running full screen but we can't see why.

To demonstrate, create a new AS2 Flash Project in Flash CS4 and add the following actionScript to Layer 1, Frame 1

> fscommand("fullscreen", true);
>
> fscommand("allowscale", true);
>
> fscommand("showmenu", false);
>
> stop();

(we've been using these fscommands since forever)

Now...

If I save the FLA and setup my Publish Settings as follows:

**Formats Tab:** Switch on Flash (.swf) and Windows Projector (.exe) only

**Flash Tab:** Player = "Flash Player 7" and Script = "ActionScript 2.0"
then "Publish"

Then running the resultant EXE goes full screen.

Setting Player = "Flash Player 8" also goes full screen.

Setting Player = "Flash Player 9" does NOT go full screen.

Setting Player = "Flash Player 10" does NOT go full screen.

And yet... I thought that the Windows Projector (.exe) completely ignored the Flash tab as demonstrated by unticking the Flash (.swf) checkbox off from the Formats tab.  I thought I undestood that a Windows Projector (.exe) always published to the latest version of Flash for that authoring tool.

Can anyone explain why the Flash tab in Publish Settings is effecting my Windows Projector (.exe)?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

However, changing

Answer (score 1):

For Flash 9/10, ensure that each second parameter to fscommand is a unique string.  For example,

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");
fscommand("allowscale", "True");  // change case of a letter!  incredible...
fscommand("showmenu", "false");
```

See this article at [northcode.com](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/09/11/FSCommand-and-getURL-Bug-in-Flash-Player-9) for a discussion. It appears that the list of getURL and fscommand calls in a frame are kept in a map that is indexed by the argument, not the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with double quotes...

fscommand("fullscreen", "true");

fscommand("allowscale", "true");

fscommand("showmenu", "false");

stop();

This will work for FLASH Play 9/10

Thanks 
Siva

Answer (score 0):

i can't believe that worked..

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");
fscommand("allowscale", "True");  // change case of a letter!  incredible...
```